# Retrieving stock updates using Yahoo Finance

Tags: jquery, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

Basically what i am trying do is retrieving stock quotes for specific company . In my code I am giving symbol of specific company(**eg:FB**) in a **textbox(symb)** and when i click the **button(getupdate)** it should list out details regarding that specific stock which i enter the text box .

Here's my code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
$('getupdate').click(function() {

        var symbol = $('input[id=symb]').val(); \\For Example:FB

        var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'+symbol+'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, val) {
                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');

            });
            $('<ul/>', { 'class': 'my-new-list', html: items.join('')}).appendTo('body');
        });
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:16px;">
    Stock Ticker : <input id="symb" type="textbox" value="Ticker"></input>
</div>
<button id="getupdate" name = "getupdate" type="button">Get Updates!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least 2 errors in code `$('getupdate')` => `$('#getupdate')` and quotes in URL (near `+symbol+`) are incorrect.

Comment: You should check and handle zero records:  if (data.query.count == 0)...  And you aren't building the query string properly.  Is the value of symbol actually being put into the url string?

Comment: @netme Thank you . I made the changes in the code . But still not able to get stock quotes for my query .

Comment: @SteveWellens I have those changes . Thank you .

Comment: @DeepeshShetty, please look on my answer. I've also fixed Yahoo query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your JS code:

1. Incorrect selector for a button: `$('getupdate')` => `$('#getupdate')`;
2. Wrong quotes inside `url` value;
3. Wrong query string to Yahoo API;
4. Wrong comment sign `\\For Example:FB`.

Your JS should be like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#getupdate').click(function() {
            var symbol = $('input[id=symb]').val(); 
            var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D%22' + symbol + '%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                var items = [];
                $('#results').html('');
                $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, val) {
                    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');

                });
                $('<ul/>', { 'class': 'my-new-list', html: items.join('')}).appendTo('#results');
            });
    });
});
```

And please add this code after `<button>` tag in your HTML. This will help you easily  clear results before new query:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6EFqk/1/

I'm not shure that ouput format is correct, please reformat it as you like.

Comment: Thank you . Its working Fine now . But the problem is when i change the text box value and click the button again it wont show me quotes of new value which i entered in text box (For example : I give the value FB in text box and click get updates it will show me quotes of FB , but when i change the value from FB to say IBM and then click the button it will show me previous stocks values of FB . Now i have to refresh every time i enter a new value to the text box . Any help ?

Comment: As, you are using `appendTo` function, it add the new content to the end. I've added new `div` and now I'm replace it's content every time. I've modified an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6EFqk/1/

Answer (score 1):

First, you aren't selecting the button correctly.

```
$('#getupdate').click(function() {
```

Secondly, your slashes are backwards for a comment, they are always forward not back.

```
//For Example:FB
```

And finally, you aren't getting any results for this reason given back by the service:

> The current table 'yahoo.finance.quotes' has been blocked. It exceeded the allotted quotas of either time or instructions

http://jsfiddle.net/RVFW3/

Comment: Thank you for the quick response . I made the necessary changes . But why is that table blocked ? I don't get the statement "It exceeded the allotted quotas of either time or instructions " .

Comment: I don't know, i've never used that service.

Comment: @Keven B Its working Fine now . But the problem is when i change the text box value and click the button again it wont show me quotes of new value which i entered in text box (For example : I give the value **FB** in text box and click get updates it will show me quotes of **FB** , but when i change the value from **FB** to say **IBM** and then click the button it will show me previous stocks values of **FB** . Now i have to refresh every time i enter a new value to the text box . Any help ?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#getupdate').click(function() {
 
   var symbol = $('input[id=symb]').val();
   
  var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'"+symbol+"'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";`

Comment: It worked fine for me . The above answer . Thanks a lot mate for the help .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28491/discussion-between-deepesh-shetty-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this stream doing a google search on the subject.

Perhaps this site will answer your questions ... http://bitbenderz.com/stockticker/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcmorgan/ZMLtJ/)

```
$.getJSON(yqlUrl1, function(data){
    $.each(data.query.results.row, function(index, item){

    var element = $('<div></div>');

    element.append('<span>' + item.symbol + '</span> ');
    element.append('<span>' + item.price + '</span> ');

    if (item.change.indexOf('+') > -1) {
        element.append('<span class="stockUp"> ' + item.change + '</span>');
    } else {
        element.append('<span class="stockDown"> ' + item.change + '</span>');
    }

    element.appendTo('#quotes');   
    });
})
```