# Fields in yahoo finance table(yahoo.finance.quotes)

Tags: jquery, database, yahoo-finance

Basically what i am trying do is retrieving stock quotes for specific company . In my code I am giving symbol of specific company(eg:FB) in a textbox(symb) and when i click the button(getupdate) it should list out details regarding that specific stock which i enter the text box .

This is question i asked before . Its just an extension of this question .

[Retrieving stock updates using Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085704/retrieving-stock-updates-using-yahoo-finance)

In query i give there is a "Select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where .... "

My question is instead of ***** can i give specific fields Like ***symbol***                            "Select symbol from yahoo.finance.quotes where .."

If yes what and all fields are available for querying .

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: you can look at this http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

Comment: @Darshan I tried querying it . It didn't help .